# Lazy parameter type in Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, casting

i have a question about parameter passing in Java. Let's say i have a method:

```
public void x(Object o)
```

Let's say i call x(3) and x("abc"). x(3) will take a little bit more time because a new Integer is constructed, since 3 is not an Object. Assuming i can't change the method calls, only the method implementation (and parameter type), is there a way to prevent this Integer construction until some point in the method x where i know it's really needed?

Thanks,
Teo

Comment: why don't you overload it like x(int)?

Comment: @John No it is not. Autoboxing works by calling the method `Integer.valueOf(3)`, which will indeed return a cached `Integer` object. If you use `new`, a new object is always created; this will not get a cached object.

Comment: @Jesper: yes. i mean to say that Integer object of value 3 is cached.

Comment: @Jesper: i removed my comment since it's not clear.

Comment: My method is actually like this `void x(Object o1, Object o2, ...)` I have 7 such signatures because i want my method to be able to take 7 parameters. I'm not using a variable number of parameters for performance reasons. So the problem is i have no way of knowing which one of the Objects will be the int.

Comment: And the same goes for boolean, double...

Comment: One way would be to use something like `if (condition) {x(3)}`. This way the int to Object cast wouldn't happen unless the condition is met. But i can't change the code where these calls happen...

Answer (score 3):

No, Java does not have a way to make it evaluate the arguments to a method lazily in the way you describe.

[Section 15.12.4](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.4) of The Java Language Specification explains exactly how method invocation works and how the arguments to a method are evaluated before it is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lazily evaluated object like Callable

```
public void method(Callable<Object> callable) {
    // if you really need it
    Object obj = callable.call();
}
```

The reason you don't see this more often is that it is usually slower and more complicated.

BTW: `x(3)` won't create an object because this is actually `x(Integer.valueOf(3))` and `valueOf` has a cache of small Integer values.

For most applications the cost of creating a very small, simple object like Integer is small compared with the complexity of creating a lazily evaluated value.

If you want to avoid object creation you could have

```
public void x(Object o) ;
public void x(int i);
```

or

```
public void x(long l);
```

or

```
public void x(double d);
```

The later example avoid creating lots of variations of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

1) There is no way to postpone the object creation

2) The difference will be that small that you don't need to care

Answer (score 0):

If the method x is only dealing with integers not any other types of objects then you can change the method to

`public void x(int x){
//do something and then create the object as needed.
}`

But in your case the method is about to take any kind of object so there is no other way other than creating a new integer object.